# Is $g(x,y)=3x-2f(x,y)+5$ differentiable at $(2,-1)$ with $z=-x+6y+1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to check if this is true or false:

> If the function $f(x,y): \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is differentiable at $(2,-1)$ with the tangent plane $z=2x-3y+2$ then the function $g(x,y)=3x-2f(x,y)+5$ is differentiable at the same point with the tangent plane $z=-x+6y+1$

I'm new to this subject, I was suggested to use the chain rule but we have not seen it in class (yet). I know that I need the partial derivatives of $g$ and for that I need the ones of $f$. So I could look into $f$'s equation for the tangent plane at $(2,-1)$ and get $f_x = 2$ and $f_y= -3$. I want to see if $g$'s tangent plane: $\Pi_{(2,-1)}:z=g(2,-1)+g_x(2,-1)(x-2)+g_y(2,-1)(y+1)$ is equal to the one given by the problem, but I'm not sure on how to differentiate $2f(2,-1)$ in $g$. Could you help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain rule or not, differentiation is still a linear operator.

$\frac {\partial }{\partial x}(f(x) + g(x)) = \frac {\partial f}{\partial x}+ \frac {\partial g}{\partial x}$
and $\frac {\partial }{\partial x}(af(x)) = a\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}$

If $f(x,y)$ is tangent to the plane $z(x,y)$ then, at the point of tangency, $f(x,y) = z(x,y)$ and  $(\frac {\partial f}{\partial x},\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}) = (\frac {\partial z}{\partial x},\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}).$  We might also write this as $\nabla f = \nabla z$

In our problem:

$\frac {\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac {\partial}{\partial x} (3x - 2f + 5) = 3\frac {\partial x}{\partial x} -2\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} = 3-4 = -1$

I will leave it to you to find $\frac {\partial g}{\partial y}$.

Next, you will need to find $g(2,-1) = 6 + 2f(2,-1) + 5$

and you know that $f(2,1)$ lies on the plane $z = 2x-3y + 2$

or $f(2,-1) = 4+3 + 2 = 9$ which is enough information to find $g.$

Answer (score 0):

Following @Doug M's answer:

With $\frac {\partial g}{\partial y} = 6$ and $g(2,-1)=-7$ now I can complete the equation for $g$'s tangent plane at $(2,-1)$:

$\Pi_{(2,-1)}:z=g(2,-1)+g_x(2,-1)(x-2)+g_y(2,-1)(y+1)$

$\Pi_{(2,-1)}:z=-7+(-1)(x-2)+6(y+1)$

$\Pi_{(2,-1)}:z=-x+6y +1$

The answer is true.